# What is the default state of a checkbox in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've a problem. I'm currently implementing a form with a checkbox validation. The problem is that the error message is visible after the initial load but it should only be visible if the form get's submitted without a checked checkbox:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <mat-checkbox [formControl]="legalCheckbox" color="primary" required>
    I agree!
  </mat-checkbox>
  <mat-error *ngIf="legalCheckbox.invalid">{{getLegalCheckboxErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
</div>
```

This is my validation:

```
legalCheckbox = new FormControl('', [Validators.requiredTrue]);

getLegalCheckboxErrorMessage() {
  if (this.legalCheckbox.hasError('required')) {
    return 'Checkbox is required';
  }
}
```

I'm really confused why the message is visible after the initial load. Does anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Technically it is invalid, but if you never touched it it shouldn't be showing the error message... can you create a reproducer (on stackblitz)?

Comment: @MikeS. Yes thats exactly what I was thinking. It should only throw an error if it get's touched and not if not. I'll try to make a reproducer.

Comment: the values are true or false, so use `legalCheckbox = new FormControl(false, [Validators.requiredTrue]);`, but you need use `*ngIf="legalCheckbox.invalid && legalCheckbox.touched`. NOTE: you dont' need use a function getLegalCheckboxErrorMessage

Comment: This is my stackblitz reproducer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u87hka somehow it don't knows the formControl attribute.

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for the explanation. But somehow it's not showing the message if I press my form submit button. The other inputs getting marked as invalid when I press the button.

Comment: in submit button, if the form is invalid, use `markAllAsTouched()` or `markAsUntouched()`, https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAllAsTouched. (or

Comment: @Eliseo Awesome! Thanks! I'm new in Angular so I'm still learning.